# Python Flask login con archivo CSV

Tags: python, csv, login, flask, txt

Estoy tratando de hacer un login que recurre a validar el email y el password en un archivo users.txt. Al ejecutarlo me sale siempre el último else >>> No existe el usuario. Agradezco si alguien detecta el error. El archivo al que está llamando mi código python es:

`users.txt` (email,contraseña):

```
user1@user,pass1
user2@user,pass2
```

Mi archivo principal es de python-flask:

`flashing.py`:

```
from flask import *
import csv

app = Flask(__name__)  
app.secret_key = "abc"  
 
@app.route('/')

def home():  
    return render_template("index.html")  
 
@app.route('/login',methods = ["GET","POST"])  
def login():
    error = None;  
    if request.method == "POST":
        with open("users.txt", "r") as file:
            file_reader = csv.reader(file)
            for row in file:
                if row[0] == request.form['email']:
                    user_found = [row[0],row[1]]
                    if user_found[1] != request.form['pass']:
                        error = "contraseña incorrecta"  
                    else:  
                        flash("estás logueado!")  
                        return redirect(url_for('home'))
                else:
                    error = "no existe el usuario"
    return render_template('login.html',error=error)  
  
if __name__ == '__main__':  
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Y mis archivos html dentro de la carpeta template son:

`login.html`:

```
<html>  
<head>  
    <title>login</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
    {% if error %}  
        <p><strong>Error</strong>: {{error}}</p>  
    {% endif %}  
  
    <form method = "post" action = "/login">  
        <table>  
            <tr><td>Email</td><td><input type = 'email' name = 'email'></td></tr>  
            <tr><td>Password</td><td><input type = 'password' name = 'pass'></td></tr>  
            <tr><td><input type = "submit" value = "Submit"></td></tr>  
        </table>  
    </form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

`index.html`:

```
<html>  
<head>  
<title>home</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}  
         {% if messages %}  
               {% for message in messages %}  
                    <p>{{ message }}</p>  
               {% endfor %}  
         {% endif %}  
      {% endwith %}  
<h3>Welcome to the website</h3>  
<a href = "{{ url_for('login') }}">login</a>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Donde pones: `for row in file:` puedes poner: `for row in file_reader:`

Comment: increible que haya sido esa distracción nomas, muchas gracias @FranciscoJavier